# Argmin inequality question

Tags: analysis, inequality, optimization

Say we have three functions $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ and we know that $\arg\min_x f(x)=\arg\min_x h(x)$.  Does it follow that $\arg\min_x f(x)=\arg\min_x g(x)=\arg\min_x h(x)$?  If it isn't true, are there some important special cases where it is true?

Comment: No. Think e.g. of mostly flat functions with a small dip somewhere, with plenty of space between then. Then $g$ can have it’s minimum anywhere.

Comment: If additionally $\min f=\min h$, then it would be true.